# text with sharp shadow around

Tags: ios, uilabel, uifont, quartz-core

**I want to achieve** the text appearance like in the pictures below:
[image]
[image]

Now I'm working on **shadow around the letters** and I can't figure out how to do that.

**What I've tried so far:**
 - The solution with:

```
label.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 2);
```

gives a nice sharp shadow, but it doesn't fit my needs by two reasons:

1. It gives a shadow only from one side, set up by *shadowOffset*, whereas I need a "wrapping" shadow;
2. This solution doesn't give the soft part of the shadow (gradient) as there is in the pictures;

-The solution with:

```
label.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
label.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
label.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
label.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
label.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
label.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

Works great, but it gives too soft shadow even though the *shadowOpacity* is set to 1 and the *shadowColor* is set to black:
[image]
Obviously it's not enough and I already think about drawing in labels' context. But it is not clear to me how would I achieve the goal even through context drawing.

Any idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: CATextLayer may help you..

Comment: Thanks to Bala's answer I reached precisely what I wanted. Perhaps not in the perfect way from the perspective of performance, though yet I can't think of a better solution. By anyone's request I'll provide my final code and its graphical result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this** 
Create a Custom `UILabel` SubClass and *`Override`* the following method

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0), 10);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0), 10, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);

    [super drawTextInRect:rect];

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

and this `bottomColorLayer` to the Label

> ```
> CALayer *bottomColorLayer = [CALayer layer];
> bottomColorLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, labelRect.size.height/2, labelRect.size.width, labelRect.size.height/2);
> bottomColorLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.5] CGColor];
> [label.layer insertSublayer:bottomColorLayer above:(CALayer *)label.layer];
> ```

[image]

**or If you want Gradient**

> ```
> CAGradientLayer *bottomGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
> bottomGradient.frame = CGRectMake(0, labelRect.size.height/2, labelRect.size.width, labelRect.size.height/2);
> bottomGradient.cornerRadius = 0.0f;
> bottomGradient.colors = @[(id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:.5] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.5] CGColor]];
> [label.layer insertSublayer:bottomGradient above:(CALayer *)label.layer];
> ```

Comment: Well, you shouldn't worry about the letters' color, the question was only about the shadow :) But your excerpt with **drawTextInRect** gave me the main push ahead. **CGContextSetShadowWithColor** uses *shadowOffset* in the same way as I mentioned in question for not working solution, but in *CGContextSetShadowWithColor* you can apply and draw the result *several* times in a row (e.g. first to draw the shadow above the text, and then under it) - and it did the trick! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try with the code below :-

```
  [_testLable setText:@"TION ERRO"];
    [_testLable setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [_testLable setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22] ];
    _testLable.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    _testLable.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0;
    _testLable.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    _testLable.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
    _testLable.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    _testLable.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

    CGPathRef shadowPath = CGPathCreateWithRect(_testLable.bounds, NULL);
    _testLable.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath;
    CGPathRelease(shadowPath);
```

Its output is like this:-

[image]

Comment: Well, this basically makes a blurred background for UILabel, since you get path just from the UILabel's bounds. Interesting but is not what I need. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use an explicit shadow path that's the shape you want. It sounds like you want a shadow the same shape as your text, but larger, with each shadow-letter centered on its corresponding letter. Once you have that, use the shadow radius to soften the edges of the shadow to whatever degree you want.

The code you have relies on the shadow radius alone to make the shadow larger than the text, which removes your ability to control the softness.